# why does text move under checkbox instead of 1 line next to checkbox?

Tags: asp.net, css, vb.net

In VB codes, before I created Div for making text change to color red during if statement, the text was aligned next to checkbox. Now when I add code for color change, `child.Text = "<div style='color:Red; display: inline; float: left;'>" + child.Text & "</div>"`, it move text under the checkbox instead of next to checkbox. I tried Span and it doesn't work. I want text to be next to checkbox.

Here is detail VB codes,

```
 'populate the child nodes
                While dr.Read()
                    Dim child As TreeNode = New TreeNode(dr("Name"), dr("Name"))
                    Dim complianceFlag As Boolean

                    If Boolean.TryParse(dr("Compliance"), complianceFlag) Then
                        ' Yes, compliance value is a Boolean, now set color based on value
                        If Not complianceFlag Then
                            child.Text = "<div style='color:Red; display: inline; float: left;'>" + child.Text & "</div>"
                        End If
                    Else

                    End If
                    rootNode.ChildNodes.Add(child)
                    child.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None
                End While
```

HTML codes,

```
<div>
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel6" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
  <asp:TreeView onclick="client_OnTreeNodeChecked();" ID="TreeViewGroups" runat="server"
          ShowCheckBoxes="All" ExpandDepth="0" CssClass="bold">
         </asp:TreeView>
    <asp:Label ID="LabelNoServers" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
   </ContentTemplate>
     <Triggers>
    <%--<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="b_DelYes" EventName="Click" />--%>
    </Triggers>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the HTML output that is generated in the page.  Sounds like you have a problem with floats that you're not understanding.

Comment: I edited it by adding HTML code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution, instead of using `<div>`, I use `<font>`. That way it will cut out the space and move back to line next checkbox.

```
child.Text = "<font color='red'>" + child.Text + "</font>"
```

Comment: I do not understand why I was downvoted. This is the only simple solution that DOES work. Div, Span, p, and other tag does not work.

Comment: It was most likely downvoted because the question was confusing in wording, you also did not show resulting HTML, you only showed the .aspx page - this is NOT rendered html.